# How can I install Snapcraft in a docker image?

Tags: docker, snapcraft

I have been trying to install `Snapcraft` inside of ubuntu 16.04. When I try to install it with:

```
snap install snapcraft --classic --beta
```

I get the error message:

> error: cannot communicate with server: Post
>   http://localhost/v2/snaps/snapcraft: dial unix /run/snapd.socket:
>   connect: no such file or directory

Installing with `apt install snapcraft` works fine but I need some features that are on the edge channel of the snap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the docker images that are based on the snaps, they are quite big though:

```
docker pull snapcore/snapcraft:<channel-risk>
```

Change `<channel-risk>` to the desired risk level, i.e.; `stable`, `candidate`, `beta` or `edge`.

These images are good to create snaps targeting `core` (in other words, 16.04 LTS based snaps)

Comment: That installs snapcraft 2.43.1, which is ages old. Current is at least 7.2.9.